# How to bubble sort an array of array's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the array of array's by the second number of each inner array.

Original array:
[[1, 7], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 10]]

Desired array after sorting:
[[3, 4], [2, 5], [1, 7], [4, 10]]

After sorting the array one time through the error "Cannot read property '1' of undefined" is thrown.

I know this is because arr[i + 1][1] is undefined because arr[i][1] is the last element in the array at the end of the loop therefore arr[i + 1][1] doesn't exist.

I've tried all the conditional statements I can think of to catch arr[i + 1][1] when it becomes undefined but haven't had any success.

How should I stop it from catching on the undefined error and instead keep iterating through the array until it's fully sorted?

```
let unsortedArr = [[1, 7], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 10]]
let sorted = false;

function sort(arr){
  while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (arr[i][1] > arr[i + 1][1]) {
          sorted = false;
          let temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
          arr[i + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(arr)
  }

  sort(unsortedArr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your

```
if (arr[i][1] > arr[i + 1][1]) {
//                    ^^^
```

which will throw once `i` is at `length - 1`. Only iterate up to `length - 2` instead:

```js
let unsortedArr = [
  [1, 7],
  [2, 5],
  [3, 4],
  [4, 10]
]
let sorted = false;

function sort(arr) {
  while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr[i][1] > arr[i + 1][1]) {
        sorted = false;
        let temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}

sort(unsortedArr)
```